# Format input field "time" to not show seconds and milliseconds

Tags: html, angularjs

in AngularJS 1.5 I have a form with an input field of type "time". It works, but the time shown should be HH:mm - without seconds, etc.

Chrome does this by default, but Firefox and Internet Explorer show with seconds and milliseconds (e.g. "14:56:00.000" instead of "14:56").

How can we show the required time format in all browsers?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-time-input-directive-production</title>
  
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body ng-app="timeExample">
  <script>
 angular.module('timeExample', [])
   .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.example = {
       value: new Date(1970, 0, 1, 14, 56)
     };
   }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
   <label for="exampleInput">Pick a time between 8am and 5pm:</label>
   <input type="time" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
       placeholder="HH:mm" min="08:00" max="17:00" required />
   <div role="alert">
     <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
         Required!</span>
     <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.time">
         Not a valid date!</span>
   </div>
   <tt>value = {{example.value | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
   <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are right. But I mean the date format in the input field, not in the text field. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Added some links which might be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox and IE don't support `<input type="time">`, it's browser dependent. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) link for more info on W3. So your input field will not be able to display it the same way as in Chrome.

An alternative is to use `uib-timepicker`from [`angular-ui`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or try one from [jquery](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/timepicker/) like [webshim](http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html).

Comment: this accepted answer is obsolete now, as time inputs are supported by all modern browsers. [as u can see here](https://caniuse.com/?search=input%20type%3D%22time%22). Is there a solution to the original question?

Answer (score 1):

try using step attribute and set it to 60".

```
<input type="time" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
   placeholder="HH:mm" min="08:00" max="17:00" required step="60" />
```

Comment: Seems this works only when you are filling the form, but not if you are showing a Date.

Comment: Work when you fill the form and populate values in the form during the update any record.

Answer (score 0):

Date time input types are not supported by IE11 and Safari. But we hope for the best and regularly visit this "can_i_use" link to see if something has changed.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Answer (score 0):

We can write a common method in controller end to not allow second and millisecond to be shown in input type time

```
getFormatDate = function (val) { // assuming val is date like "/Date(946673340000)/"
 if (val != undefined) {
    date = new Date(val.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1); // creating a date object from val
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 
  date.getHours(), date.getMinutes());
 }
}
```